# Is there a history of friend requests received?

Tags: facebook

On Facebook, I would like to see all *Friend Requests* I ever received. Is it possible?

The current list of Friend requests is not good enough for several reasons:

1. Only unaccepted friend requests are displayed. Once I accept the person as a friend, and I want to see if it was me or him/her who sent the request, I can't.
2. There was some mess around the friendship being recommended, so I want to be absolutely sure if the request was actually sent from that person alone.

In other words, is there a **complete** history of friend requests that have been sent to me?

Answer (score 1):

In Facebook you can view recieved friend request history in the Activity Log.

#### Steps

1. Click your profile picture at the top right of the page
2. Select <kbd>Settings & Privacy</kbd>
3. Then <kbd>Activity Log</kbd>
4. Then <kbd>Connections</kbd>
5. Then <kbd>Recieved friend requests</kbd>

There are also other options related to friend requests in the Connections section of the  Activity Log.

Reference: [Find your Facebook activity log](https://www.facebook.com/help/289066827791446)